# Assign dynamic tpl to combo in grid

Tags: extjs4

I have a grid in that one column has editor of type combo. This combo fills dynamically. Right now i can show only one column in its drop down list but i want to show more than one column in its drop down list. each drop down list may contain different column names.

I succeed in creating tpl string but fail to assign this tpl to combo.

My logic is:

1. create grid
2. in focus event- fill combo dynamically and create tpl
3. assign tpl to combo
4. show drop down list by expand method.

Please suggest me if there is any method like combo.setTpl(tpl_string)

Logic Description:

### 1. Created model which will hold two columns

```
i. column_name: Name of column from data base.
ii. data_type: Data type of column

Ext.define('modelTableStructure',
{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:
    [
        { name: 'column_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'data_type', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

### 2. Created store which will use model in step 1

```
  var storeTableStructure = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',
  {
    model: 'modelTableStructure',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy
    ({
        type: 'ajax',
        reader:
        {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows',
            idProperty: 'column_name'
         }// reader end
    }), // proxy end
        listeners:
    {
        load: onLoadStore
    }

});
```

### 3. This is to change data type of columns as per EXT JS

```
var type_lookup = new Object;
type_lookup['int'] = 'numberfield';
type_lookup['float'] = 'numberfield';
type_lookup['string'] = 'textfield';
type_lookup['date'] = 'datefield';
type_lookup['boolean'] = 'checkbox';
type_lookup['varchar'] = 'textfield';
type_lookup['bit'] = 'checkbox';
```

### 4. This is a model and store of a combo

```
Ext.define('modelTableData',
{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
});

var storeDataID = new Ext.data.JsonStore
({
    model: 'modelTableData',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy
    ({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'url to get data',
        reader:
        {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'rows',
            idProperty: 'primary key column name'
         }
        }) 
});
```

### 5. Here is the method which will get called on store load which we created in step 2

```
function onLoadStore() {
var cnt = storeTableStructure.getCount();
fields = [];
var colNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    var Col_nm = storeTableStructure.getAt(i).data.column_name;
    var Col_Type = storeTableStructure.getAt(i).data.data_type;
    colNames[i] = Col_nm;
    fields[i] = {
        name: Col_nm,
        type: Col_Type,
        editor:
        {
            xtype: type_lookup[Col_Type]
        }
    };
}
DataID_createHeaderTPL(colNames);
modelTableData.setFields(fields, 'COL_PK_ID', 'COL_PK_ID');
var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy
({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'TestCase.ashx?methodname=getdataids&stepdisplayname=name',
    reader:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'rows',
        idProperty: 'COL_PK_ID'
    }// reader end
 });  // proxy end

proxy.setModel(modelTableData, true)
storeDataID.setProxy(proxy);
storeDataID.load({
    url: 'TestCase.ashx?methodname=getdataids&stepdisplayname=name'
});
};

var tplDataid = '';

function DataID_createHeaderTPL(colNames) {
var hd = '';
var td = '';
for (var i_f = 0; i_f < colNames.length; i_f++) {
    hd = hd + '<th width=100> ' + colNames[i_f] + ' </th>';
    td = td + '<td width=100> {' + colNames[i_f] + '} </td>';
}

tplDataid = '<tpl>' +
            '<table width=500>' +
                    '<tr style="text-align: left;">' +
                        hd +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</table>' +
            '</tpl>' +
            '<tpl for=".">' +
                '<div class="x-boundlist-item">' +
                    '<table width=500>' +
                        '<tr>' +
                            td +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</table>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</tpl>';
}
```

### 6. This function is creating my grid.

```
function showRecordDetails() {
storeTableStructure.load({
    url: 'TestCase.ashx?methodname=gettablestructure&stepdisplayname=name'
});

    Ext.define('gridTCStep',
{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.gridTCStep',

    requires:
    [
        'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',
        'Ext.form.field.Text',
        'Ext.toolbar.TextItem'
    ],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        });
        Ext.apply(this,
        {
            store: StoreTCStep,
            width: 980,
            height: 340,
            plugins: [this.editing],
            columns:
            [
                {
                    id: "DATA_ID",
                    header: "Data ID",
                    minWidth: 50,
                    dataIndex: 'DATA_ID',
                    flex: 3,
                    editor:
                    {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        forceSelection: true,
                        store: storeDataID,
                        hideTrigger: true,
                        displayField: 'Data_ID',
                        valueField: 'Data_ID',
                        enableKeyEvents: true,
                        matchFieldWidth: false,
                        listeners:
                        {
                            'focus': DataID_Focus,
                            'keypress': combo_KeyPress
                        },
                        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', tplDataid),
                        displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                            '<tpl for=".">',
                                '{Data_ID}',
                            '</tpl>'
                        )
                    }
                }
            ]
        }); // EXT.APPLY
        this.callParent();
    } //in it component
}); // gridTCStep end

    button = Ext.get('btnNewEntry');
    var lblWd = 90;

    var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel
({
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 5px 5px',
    submitEmptyText: true,
    items:
    [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            name: 'gridpanel',
            shadow: false,
            items:
                [
                    {
                        id: 'griddata',
                        items: gridTCStep,
                        store: StoreTCStep
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]// items

});       // form panel end

    win = Ext.create('widget.window',
    {
        closable: true,
        frame: false,
        closeAction: 'destroy',
        width: 1000,
        minWidth: 350,
        height: 600,
        shadow: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        items:
        [
            {
                id: 'westpanel',
                name: 'westpanel',
                items: formPanel
            }
        ]// items of window
    }); // Window creation


    win.show();          // win.show end

}; // function end
```

### 7. On focus event of combo i am calling this function. In this function i loaded store created in step 2. so that combo will filled by new record and as per new records it will have multiple columns. You can see tpl is created in store load event.

```
   function DataID_Focus(combo, records, eOpts) {
    storeTableStructure.load({
        url: 'TestCase.ashx?methodname=gettablestructure&stepdisplayname=name'
    });

    combo.tpl = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', tplDataid);
    combo.expand();
   };
```

Comment: Could you show us your code so far?

Comment: Hi Alex Filipovici, I have added my code, please go through it, if you get some doubt ask me but do tell me if you got any solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the template to the BoundList of the combo, and not in an event, but when you create it (or extend it). I think the option you're searching is [`Ext.view.BoundList#tpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-cfg-tpl).

You won't create the BoundList yourself, but you can pass it some config option with [`Ext.form.field.ComboBox#listConfig`](http://dev.vm/ext-4.2/docs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig) list this:

```
Ext.widget('combobox', {
    listConfig: {
        tpl: myTpl
    }
    // ...
});
```

### Edit: how to make that dynamic

See bellow the implementation of the `setListTpl` method.

```
// example templates
var templates = [
    Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', [
        '<tpl for=".">',
             '<div style="background-color: {color};">{text}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ])
    ,Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', [
        '<tpl for=".">',
             '<div style="color: {color};">{text}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ])    
];

var combo = Ext.widget('combo', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,store: {
        fields: ['text', 'color']
        ,data: [
            {text: 'Foo', color: 'red'}
            ,{text: 'Bar', color: 'green'}
            ,{text: 'Baz', color: 'blue'}
        ]
    }

    // initial template
    ,listConfig: {
        tpl: templates[0]
    }

    // changes the list template dynamically
    ,setListTpl: function(tpl) {
        var picker = this.getPicker();    
        picker.tpl = tpl;
        picker.refresh();
    }
});

// example usage: alternate between template on each expand
combo.getPicker().on('beforeshow', function() {
    var nextTpl = templates.shift();
    templates.push(nextTpl);
    combo.setListTpl(nextTpl);
});
```

Comment: I am getting error on setListTpl() method and setListTpl: config. Which version you are using? I use 4.2.0

Comment: i construct my new tpl in expand event also new store for combo is created in expand event. so i am assigning new tpl in expand event. beforeshow event doesn't executes, why?

Comment: It is working with 4.2 in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/Ubf77/). What error are you getting?

Comment: It's too late for changing the template, in the expand event. See [the code of the expand method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Picker.html#Ext-form-field-Picker-method-expand): the event is fired after the picker has been shown. Are you sure you're listening the beforeshow event **on the BoundList**, not the combo (see my code example)?

Comment: I moved my code in focus event. In focus event i am filling my store for combo, creating tpl, then assigning this tpl to combo and then calling expand. latest code is also uploaded with this question. And one more thing, my combo is in grid and i am not creating it as you. I am creating it in columns editor config. Please check my code once again and let me know any correction in code.

Comment: You created one template of all tpl. But in my case i would have to create this template dynamically which is not feasible. Please give me a code which will have tpl stored in string variable and i assign this variable to combo

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't debug your code for you... You may start by checking that everything is called in the order you expect. For example in your last function, you're using tplDataid that has probably not yet been updated from the previous **async** storeTableStructure.load call. Anyway, we're way out of the scope of the question here, if you need more help I advice you assemble a complete example that one can copy-paste in jsFiddle and ask another question...

Comment: I got it rixo, Thanks a lot. Actually i was not getting setListTpl config. It is not a confing in documents also but we can add it and call it. I called it from focus event with new tpl string. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer, thanks a lot rixo. It is so simple refer my code and some updations are:

### 1. add setListTpl config to your combo though it is described in documents it does job of updating tpl and call this config from wherever you want. I called it from focus event, see second updation for how to call

```
     ......
     editor:
                {
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    store: storeDataID,
                    hideTrigger: true,
                    displayField: 'Data_ID',
                    valueField: 'Data_ID',
                    enableKeyEvents: true,
                    matchFieldWidth: false,
                    listeners:
                    {
                        'focus': DataID_Focus,
                        'keypress': combo_KeyPress
                    },
                    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', tplDataid),
                    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                            '{Data_ID}',
                        '</tpl>'
                    ),
                    setListTpl: function(tpl) {
                            var picker = this.getPicker();
                            picker.tpl = tpl;
                            picker.refresh();
                        }
                }
            }
     ....
```

### 2. Call setListTpl config from focus event of combo as:

```
     function DataID_Focus(combo, records, eOpts) {
    storeTableStructure.load({
        url: 'url to load store'
    });

    combo.setListTpl(Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', newTplstring));
    combo.expand();
};
```