# Assigning to value to local variable from global variable in focus event in extjs

Tags: extjs4

I was having a question as [Assign dynamic tpl to combo in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16828766/2393573), i solved it but i to see correct tpl i have to get focus out of combo first and then again set focus to combo. If i follow this process then and then only i can see correct list else previous tpl is shown. My code in **combo_focus event** is

```
..//
    var tmp = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', tplDataid);
    combo.setListTpl(tmp);
    combo.expand();
//..
```

if i replace code with

```
 ..//
    alert('Beftore tmp:' + tplDataid);
    var tmp = Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', tplDataid);
    alert('After tmp:' + tplDataid);
    combo.setListTpl(tmp);
    combo.expand();
//..
```

first alert box shows tpl as

```
Beftore tmp:<br><tpl><table width=400><tr style="text-align: left;">
<th width=100> COL_PK_ID </th><th width=100> Data_ID </th><th width=100> 
Col1 </th><th width=100> col2 </th></tr></table></tpl><tpl for=".">
<div class="x-boundlist-item"><table width=400><tr><td width=100> {COL_PK_ID} 
</td><td width=100> {Data_ID} </td><td width=100> {Col1} </td><td width=100> 
{col2} </td></tr></table></div></tpl>
```

and second alert box shows tpl as

```
After tmp:<br><tpl><table width=200><tr style="text-align: left;"><th width=100>
COL_PK_ID </th><th width=100> Data_ID </th></tr></table></tpl><tpl for=".">
<div class="x-boundlist-item"><table width=200><tr><td width=100> {COL_PK_ID} 
</td><td width=100> {Data_ID} </td></tr></table></div></tpl>
```

as we click on ok button of alert focus changes from combo to ok button and when we expands combo correct tpl is shown.

Actually i am confused what to ask so i wrote whole the process. Instead of using variable for tpl if i use session same thing happens. If i try to read columns of store same thing happens. Is it a draw back of EXT JS or something else? Somebody please help me...

Comment: Is there any method to refresh combo in its focus event?